# iOS - How to display a ppt file page by page

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-2d

I want to rendering a ppt(or pptx) file to a list of images.

Many thanks~

Comment: I know of no open source library that will do this. So your option is to send the file over a networks to some "service" you find or create that will do the work for you, perhaps actually driving Power Point or Open Office, or some Google service, the receive the images back, and then show them. Its possible that you could port Open Office (assuming it knows about PPT format) to iOS, but it would be a massive amount of work (I support an Excel library that is hugely complex).

Comment: @DavidH Yah,that will be a huge work.And my purpose is to make the function just in the device.I saw some javascript code that can get the size of every slide in the ppt.I'm trying rendering the images of the ppt file from a UIWebView.Although it is a inefficient way to solve this problem.